# Getting null pointer exception while run my code with TestNG and Cucumber?

Tags: java, cucumber, testng

Getting "Null pointer Exception" while Run my code.

[Runner class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARYUF.png)

[Main Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1f5f.png)

Comment: From review. [Please don't post screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1040347) of text. They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. Marking question *Unsalvageable*.

Comment: Please post the code directly here instead of posting link to the code.

Comment: okay. I will do it for further things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The driver instance initialized in your TestRunner class inside the @BeforeSuite method is not retrieved inside SignIn class automatically. You should create a getter method to get the driver object from TestRunner to SignIn class or use the inheritance concept to get the driver. This is the reason why you are getting a NullPointerException. You are trying to access a driver object that is not initialized in SignIn class.

Comment: But I have a doubt, Should I initiate each and every class?

Comment: @VinothSelvam no driver initialization should be done only once. But, If you are running your tests in parallel, then each thread should have its own driver instance(in this case driver should be initialized and maintained separately for each thread). You can use a getter method to get the driver instance wherever required in your case. If you are using parallelism then try using Threadlocal datatype to maintain the driver instance. Research more about this on google.